# How to align right every new line in latex parbox

Tags: parbox

How to align right every new line which I made using \ in parbox?

I've used parbox in latex for creating different part in latex business card.
On the left side I've used parbox and it is automatically left aligned.

How to create parbox on the right side of business card and align them right?

This is my latex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[zw32010,crossmark]{ticket}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[paperwidth=80mm, paperheight=50mm]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{}
\newcommand{\vcard}[5]{\ticket{
    \put(40, 25){\tt \LARGE #1}
    \put(4, 10){\tt #2}
    \put(52, 10){\tt #3}
}}

\newcounter{numcards}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{numcards}{0}

\whiledo{\thenumcards<1}{
  \stepcounter{numcards}
  \vcard
  {\includegraphics[width=40mm]{logo}}
  {\parbox{\textwidth}{\scriptsize \myfont{Comapny LTD \\Company address \\ 11000 Belgrade, Serbia \\www.company.com}}}
  {\parbox{\textwidth}{\scriptsize \myfont{M: +381 (0)11 22 33 444\\  T: +381 (0)11 22 33 445\\ F: +381 (0)11 22 33 446 \\  nn.person@gmail.com}}}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\raggedleft`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[zw32010,crossmark]{ticket}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[paperwidth=80mm, paperheight=50mm]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{}
\newcommand{\vcard}[5]{\ticket{
    \put(40, 25){\tt \LARGE #1}
    \put(4, 10){\tt #2}
    \put(52, 10){\tt #3}
}}

\newcounter{numcards}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{numcards}{0}

\whiledo{\thenumcards<1}{
  \stepcounter{numcards}
  \vcard
  {\includegraphics[width=40mm]{example-image}}
  {\parbox{\textwidth}{\scriptsize \myfont{Company LTD \\Company address \\ 11000 Belgrade, Serbia \\www.company.com}}}
  {\parbox{.5\textwidth}{\scriptsize\raggedleft \myfont{M: +381 (0)11 22 33 444\\  T: +381 (0)11 22 33 445\\ F: +381 (0)11 22 33 446 \\  nn.person@gmail.com}}}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]